# logging.info doesn't show up on console but warn and error do

Tags: python, logging, warnings, python-logging

When I log an event with `logging.info`, it doesn't appear in the Python terminal.

```
import logging
logging.info('I am info')  # no output
```

In contrast, events logged with `logging.warn` do appear in the terminal.

```
import logging
logging.warn('I am warning')  # outputs "I am warning"
```

Is there a environment level change I can to make `logging.info` print to the console? I want to avoid making changes in each Python file.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The root logger always defaults to WARNING level. Try calling

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: this works well, but I think I will have to change it in every python file I have right? there is no global setting for LOGGING

Comment: No, you only need to call it once. The logger is built as a hierarchy with and all logging boils down to a *root logger*. By not specifying any argument to `getLogger()`, it is returning you the root logger. As long as you don't modify the other loggers you only need to modify the root logger.

Comment: Do you know why logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) doesn't work? I can't see it clearly on the documentation.

Comment: Isn't `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` the preferred way to do that?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 If you only have a single root logger that's likely best-practises, yes.

Comment: This Does not work on Python 3.5:
`Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)`
`[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux`
`>>> import logging`
`>>> rootLog = logging.getLogger()`
`>>> rootLog.setLevel(logging.INFO)`
`>>> rootLog.info('all the kings horses')`
`>>> rootLog.warning('all the kings men')`
`all the kings men`

Comment: FWIW, this post explains why the root logger and logging module level method calls are best avoided:  https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2017/08/06/understanding-pythons-logging-module/   The tl;dr is:  "Don’t log directly against the root logger. That means: no logging.basicConfig() and no usage of module-level loggers such as logging.warning(), as they have unintended side-effects."

Comment: @jeffk, same with me 3.6.8 doesn't print info messages even when setLevel is set to logging.INFO

Comment: @RobertLugg Same here in 3.7, set my logger to logging.INFO and nothing is showing up unless I use logger.warning()

Comment: Use "root" to actually set the root.
I.E. "logging.root.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)"

Comment: Will this method have unintended consequences? I'm just afraid that reconfiguring root logger after having child loggers is not the best idea. I'm not well-versed in python's logging,

Comment: This will not work for Python 3.2 and later, since root logger without explict handlers will use the logging.lastResort handler and its level is WARNING. See also the official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided.

Comment: Sometimes defining a stream helps: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 52):

Like @ztyx said that default logger level is WARNING. You have to set it to a lower level

You can do it by using [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) and setting [logger level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels):

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I'm wondering why `basicConfig()` doesn't work for me, although `logging.getLogger().setLevel()` suitably work?

Comment: @ShayanAmani - According to the documentation, "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument force is set to True."

Answer (score 31):

The above solutions didn't work for me, but the code [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) did:

```
# set up logging to file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

(I omitted parts of the code for the sake of readability)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I had a line with `logging.error("Connection timed out!")` and even with the `level=logging.DEBUG` in the `basicConfig()`, it wouldn't print to console. Adding the handler did, thanks so much!!

Comment: Keep in mind that the handler you are using is playing a role. If, for example, your code had the NullHandler, nothing would be printed regardless of the logging lever.

Comment: Same here - if i omit the level argument in `basicConfig` or set it above INFO then the console logger will never log anything. If i leave out `basicConfig` then i can call `setLevel` on a logger all day (and i can see the level change by calling `getEffectiveLevel`) but it will never log anything below `WARNING` level. I'm not actually sure that that isnt the correct behaviour but its not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 18):

This will work

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('its working')
```

Answer (score 7):

In more recent versions of Python 3 (tested with Python 3.8), console logging requires creating a console handler to correctly show `info` messages.

The following example is modified from the [Configuring Logging example](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) in the Python documentation:

```py
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')
level = logging.INFO
logger.setLevel(level)

# ----> console info messages require these lines <----
# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(level)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
# -----------------------------------------------------

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

Running the above code generates the following output:

```bash
info message
warn message
error message
critical message
```

Here is this same code without the console handler.

```py
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')
level = logging.INFO
logger.setLevel(level)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

Without the console handler, the output does not include the info message:

```bash
warn message
error message
critical message
```

I do not understand why this is the case as it seems unnecessary.

Comment: weird, I can confirm streamhandler is necessary. Thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 4):

What's the minimum required code for a working module-level logger? I did an experiment (with python version 3.8.6).

The take-away is:

- `logging.basicConfig()` is needed (however, specifying `level=...` is NOT needed)
- it's *necessary* to configure the root logger: `logging.getLogger().setLevel(...)`

So, a minimum working example is:

The **library/module code** does NOT need to configure the logger:

```py
# library/module code: lib.py
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('x.y.z')

def some_function():
    LOGGER.info("hi")
```

The **application code** need to configure the logger with 2 lines at minimum:

```py
# Application Code
import logging, lib

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)  # configure root logger

main()  # code that will trigger lib
```

Here's the experiment:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: lg = logging.getLogger('x.y.z')

In [3]: lg.info(1)

In [4]: logging.basicConfig()

In [5]: lg.info(1)

In [6]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

In [7]: lg.info(1)

In [8]: logging.basicConfig()

In [9]: logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

In [10]: lg.info(1)
INFO:x.y.z:1
```

Comment: Why isn't `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` enough? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django to power your server, you just simply need to change the log level in your settings.py file as such:

```
"handlers": {
                "console": {
--                  "level": "WARNING",
++                  "level": "INFO",
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "formatter": "stackdriver",
                }
            },
```

More examples in the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging-1

Answer (score 0):

For those using `absl.logging`, the equivalent command is

```
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

`logging.info()` will use the root logger for logging.

According to [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided),
if you do not set an explicit handler for the logger, a special handler called `lastResort` will be used.
See the [code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e34b494a08015e9b5a3deade23943bdba284a93/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1727-L1733). By default the logging level of `lastResort` (it is stream handler) is 30.
we can change its level to output info message.

```py
# setting both the logger and handler's level will work as expected.
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.lastResort.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

However, this is like a hack and never a encouraged action.

## Using logging.basicConfig()

If we want to do logging real quick, we can use the method [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This will create the logger. The logger.level will be the level we set here.
A stream handler will be also created, with level NOTSET.
Without a level param, the default level for root logger is WARNING.

## reference

- logger logging without handler: [logger logging without a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64570918/6064933)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use config like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", filename=f"./logs/app_log_{datetime}.log")
```