# How to use Python's built in logger for INFO messages

Tags: python, logging

I am having difficulty with the built-in logger module. WARNING messages show up but not INFO messages. Like so:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.info('Info')  # This line was inserted.
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.warning('Warning')
WARNING:root:Warning
>>> logging.info('Info')
>>>
```

Interestingly, after walking away from my desk for an hour or so and then starting a new session I got the following:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.warning('Warning')
WARNING:root:Warning
>>> logging.info('Info')
INFO:root:Info
>>>
```

It worked! The question is why did the first version not work.

Note: The question has been edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logging.info doesn't show up on console but warn and error do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548674/logging-info-doesnt-show-up-on-console-but-warn-and-error-do)

Comment: Strange. That would be the expected behaviour if you hadn't set the `level=logging.DEBUG` parameter. It works for me as expected as you have it though.

Comment: The code in Thomas's link worked for me. Check out my answer below with the line of code that worked.

Comment: FYI: There is a bug in PyScripter (which is otherwise a great debugging environment) and it does not properly display logging messages when using the recommended remote Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused with your output, it may worth to try again using just the logging code: e.g.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.warning('warning')
WARNING:root:warning
>>> logging.debug('debug')
DEBUG:root:debug
>>> logging.info('info')
INFO:root:info
```

you may refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html to get more details.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again using your code and it worked. That led me to trace down the problem. See the revised question.

Answer (score -1):

The default level that `logging` is set to is warning. Any messages below that level(such as info messages) do not display. To change that, use this code:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

**Reference:**

[logging.info doesn't show up on console but warn and error do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548674/logging-info-doesnt-show-up-on-console-but-warn-and-error-do)