# logger logging without a handler

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Why is it that a script which has:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warning("warning message")
```

will emit a message to stderr despite not having a handler? Subsequently calling:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info("info_message")
```

doesn't log anything unless I first attach a handler. Checked the hierarchy and this loggers parent is the root which also doesn't have a handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is a `logging.lastResort` handler

> A `handler of last resort` is available through this attribute. This
> is a StreamHandler writing to sys.stderr with a level of WARNING, and
> is used to handle logging events in the absence of any logging
> configuration. The end result is to just print the message to
> sys.stderr. This replaces the earlier error message saying that “no
> handlers could be found for logger XYZ”. If you need the earlier
> behaviour for some reason, lastResort can be set to None.
>
> New in version 3.2.

You didn't set the logging level for your logger, so it is `NOTSET`. It accepts any log record and propagates to the root logger.

The root logger level has a default level of `WARNING` so only log records with this level is processed.

Since there is no handler in root, `lastResort` handler is used.

Comment: Also it is critical to point out that the level of `lastResort` handler is by default `WARNING`. So even if you change the logger level to `DEBUG`, the message won't pass the `lastResort` handler.