# Logger not printing INFO level logs - Python 3.10

Tags: python, logging

I'm using this code in all my Python scripts for logging:

```
import logging

# Define the setup_logger function (similar to the one you provided)
def setup_logger(dtc_name, log_dir, is_debug=False, is_interactive=False):
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(process)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

    logger = logging.getLogger(dtc_name)
    if logger.handlers:
        for handler in logger.handlers[:]:
            logger.removeHandler(handler)

    info_log = logging.FileHandler(f"{log_dir}/{dtc_name}.log")
    info_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    info_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(info_log)

    error_log = logging.FileHandler(f"{log_dir}/{dtc_name}_error.log")
    error_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    error_log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(error_log)

    console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
    console_log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(console_log)

    if is_debug:
        console_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    elif is_interactive:
        console_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return logger

# Usage example
def main():
    # Set up the logger with debug mode enabled
    logger = setup_logger('ExampleLogger', '.', is_debug=False, is_interactive=False)
    
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        print(f"Handler: {handler} | Level: {logging.getLevelName(handler.level)}")
    
    # Log some messages at different levels
    logger.debug('This is a debug message')
    logger.info('This is an info message')
    logger.warning('This is a warning message')
    logger.error('This is an error message')
    logger.critical('This is a critical message')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

No matters if is_debug and is_interactive variables are True or False the info logs are never printed, even if the handler is on INFO level:

```
$ python3 test_logger.py
Handler: <FileHandler /mnt/c/3e/datacollector/lib/pylib/ExampleLogger.log (INFO)> | Level: INFO
Handler: <FileHandler /mnt/c/3e/datacollector/lib/pylib/ExampleLogger_error.log (ERROR)> | Level: ERROR
Handler: <StreamHandler <stderr> (INFO)> | Level: INFO
2023-11-27 16:42:16,304 244 WARNING - This is a warning message
2023-11-27 16:42:16,305 244 ERROR - This is an error message
2023-11-27 16:42:16,305 244 CRITICAL - This is a critical message
```

Is there something obviously wrong or I'm missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [logging.info doesn't show up on console but warn and error do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548674/logging-info-doesnt-show-up-on-console-but-warn-and-error-do) Tl;Dr other than the handler the logger also has a logging level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the level on the logger too - the default is `WARNING`, so you need to set the level to a lower value to see messages at that level. See [this diagram](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for more information on how things work.